# Sending Blobs from MYSQL to Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I need to send a "longBlob" type from MYSQL to Oracle 12c DB
I have a Db link that connect the two databases together so I can select the longblob file from the MySql and insert it into a Blob type in Oracle

When I select the MySql file from Oracle I can save it to the desktop and the complete file is saved, but when I try to add it to a table with a Blob type in oracle, it only saves half of the file.

What would be the best way to bring it across

I have tried to save it in a blob, Clob and even a raw type but everytime it only saves half of the file.

Could any body give me some direction to save the file in Oracle table?
Regards

Comment: How are you selecting the data back out of Oracle? How do you know it is being truncated on the insert and not on the select?

Comment: When I do a select on the table inside MYSQL from oracle I can see the size is 700kb from toad I can save the file to hdd and if you open it the image is there.

Once I insert the file from the Mysql table into the Oracle table it is 300kb and if you open the file it is half an image.

So my thinking is somewhere between the MYSQL select and inserting into a Oracle table the data is lost.

Thats why I want to know what the best way is to insert into oracle side